# how to make rails-issued cookie work cross subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, cookies

I am having a situation when I am trying to make a RAILS application to be the backend core of my APIs. I am using 'devise' to authenticate the users, which does by putting a session cookie. This is so far perfect. and take in consideration that I am building this on "api.mydomain.com"

Now, I also have a javascript application running on "mydomain.com" which do AJAX calls to the API on the subdomain. I need to have the rails-issued cookie be valid and go on the headers when I make the API calls... It just doesn't.

I tried every single solution that I found on google, where it looks like putting this

```
Api::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_api_session', :domain => ".mydomain.com"
```

into my config/initializers/session_store.rb was the default answer. this didn't work for me. 
I also found some other recommendation on google that I shoudl put that in the environment file. that didn't work either for me.

Help will be appreciated.

**Please note:** I am running rails 3.2.11 should this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `:domain => :all` option.

Source: [Railsapps Tutorial on Subdomains](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-subdomains.html) (search for "Optional: Allow Sessions To Be Shared Across Subdomains")

Comment: Thanks, Thomas .. but this didn't work either. and according to some posts, this would only work on the 1-part ltd (like localhost) and won't do the subdomains!

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a better way to do that:

```
:domain => "*.domain.com"
```